# Do I have to deallocate the memory after mfc application get closed by user?

Tags: c++, mfc

when closing an mfc application by the user, will it deallocate its memory Automatically?

Here is an example.

myapplication.h:

```
class myapplication: public CDialog
{
//declaring an mfc application

public:
bool isopen();// a flag which tells if the application is opened
}
```

mainclass.h:

```
#include myapplication.h
class mainclass
{
private:
myapplication* pmyapp;
public:
int openmyapp();
}
```

mainclass.cpp:

```
int mainclass::opendialog()
{

   if(!pmyapp->isopen()) // this means the application was opened then closed by the user, this seems to work fine
   {
     // this seems to be important to make sure of a proper closing and deallocation of the memory
     delete pmyapp;
     pmyapp = NULL;

   }
   pmyapp = new myapplication();
   pmyapp->Create(myapplication::IDD);
   pmyapp->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

So, if I open the dialog several times I run into DebugBreak()...

Comment: Yes the memory is freed after the process ended! _'... I tun into DebugBreak() ...'_ Elaborate please!!

Comment: When the app is closed, how is it possible to call `opendialog`? Or you're just closing a dialog?

Comment: All memory owned by a process gets returned to the system after a process is terminated. Your problem is elsewhere. However, leaking memory is usually a sign of sloppy programming. It can (and usually will) result in other kinds of leaks/failures.

Comment: Do you mean "dialog" closed?

Comment: @MM. myapplication is closed but not the mainclass!

Comment: @Amardeep Yes. dialog closed and opened several times

Comment: You're calling ShowWindow without having called Create first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is running after closing that dialog, **yes** you must destruct objects.

If the application is finishing, you should destruct them too. However any modern OS will clean up the whole allocated memory.

Comment: @M M. if this is the case, then why I cannot open and close the dialog several times. Since, the memory is deallocated in my code!

Comment: @Samer: Then I guess the problem is related to somewhere that you didn't show us yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your operating system will (probably) free any memory you neglect to. But it's still a bad idea, because if you don't release memory you allocate and your application runs for a long time, sooner or later you'll run out. And even if it's just one-time allocations we're talking about, if you get used to ignoring a bunch of memory leak messages at shutdown, you'll miss ones that matter more.

Further, as mentioned in the comments, if you don't `delete` class objects, then even though the OS will ultimately free the memory they occupy, their destructors will never run.

Comment: You might also want to add that not deleting heap objects means that their destructors will not get called (even if their memory is reclaimed by the OS) and this might/does lead to all kinds of other problems if they do actual work in their destructors.

Comment: @yzt Good point; edited